# select DISTINCT email based off of matching ID across tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull unique emails that have matching IDs across two tables.

```
SELECT line_items.order_id, line_items.id, orders.email, orders.name
FROM orders INNER JOIN
     line_items
     ON orders.id = line_items.order_id
WHERE line_items.order_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM orders WHERE status = 0 AND created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW() )
LIMIT 50;
```

I know my error is based upon the fact that the line_items.order_is is an INT and therefore the IN parameter is looking for another int column to match against. However, I'm not sure how to modify this to get pull the proper results. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You can either pull distinct order id's or use email in the where clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to pull unique emails that have matching IDs across two tables.

If you mean distinct emails, then your subquery would appear to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.email
FROM o.orders
WHERE o.status = 0 AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW();
```

Because an order should have at least one line item, I don't see why that table is necessary.

Your query comes close to answering the question:  "Pull all orders for emails that have made a recent order with status 0".  If that is what you want:

```
SELECT li.order_id, li.id, o.email, o.name
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     line_items li
     ON o.id = li.order_id
WHERE o.email IN (SELECT o2.email FROM orders o2 WHERE o2.status = 0 AND o2.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW() )
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Actually just got to this point as well, and it's close. I only want to return 1 record assoc to an email. I only want to pull the 1st image (line_items.id) per email. It's currently returning every row. 
Current query looks like this:


    SELECT li.order_id, li.id, o.email, o.name
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     line_items li
     ON o.id = li.order_id
WHERE o.email IN (SELECT DISTINCT o2.email FROM orders o2 WHERE o2.email != '' AND o2.email IS NOT NULL AND o2.status = 0 AND o2.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW() )
LIMIT 50;

Answer (score 1):

Hard to follow but I think you want:

```
SELECT sub.order_id, sub.line_item_id, sub.email, o.name
FROM  
(SELECT o.email, MIN(o.id) AS order_id, MIN(i.id) AS line_item_id
 FROM orders o
 INNER JOIN line_items i
 ON o.id = i.order_id
 WHERE o.status = 0
 AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW()
 GROUP BY o.email) sub
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON sub.order_id = o.id
```

In the sub-query, select each email along with the first order ID and line item ID. Then join this back to orders to pull the order name. This does assume that the MIN(line_item) will show up with the MIN(order_id) for each email, so you'll have to let me know if that is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Thanks. This is very close (and much cleaner than my initial attempt!). 
But it is still returning multiple results associated to the same email address. I only want a single result per email. Thoughts?

Comment: Not possible unless you are including other columns in the return results... The query above will give you one row per email

Comment: We can include other columns if needed. Here is where I'm at w/ the query (but as mentioned, it's returning mult records per email, and I only want 1):


    SELECT DISTINCT o.email, o.name, i.order_id, i.id 
    FROM orders o
INNER JOIN line_items i
    ON o.id = i.order_id
    WHERE o.status = 0
    AND o.email IS NOT NULL 
    AND o.email != '' 
    AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND NOW();

Comment: The reason you are getting more than one result per row is because there are multiple email, name, order id, line item id combos... If you only want unique emails, but there are multiple orders associated with the email, for example, which order do you want to display?

Comment: I just need to get the first li.order_id that matches the o.id associated to an email address.

Comment: The MIN function is giving me the following error:  

ERROR:  function min(uuid) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT o.email, MIN(i.order_id)  

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: also I assume you meant to update with i.order_id right?

Comment: Updated - try it now

Comment: 1. Thank you for all your help
2. Looks like there was an extra ')' at the end of ln3
3. Still getting the "function min(uuid) does not exist" error

One note for what it's worth, I'm running this in Heroku Dataclips.

Comment: Seems incredibly unlikely to me that this is what's wanted :-(

Comment: Nope. It just doesn't seem to like the MIN function for some reason. Worst case scenario I can dump this out to Excel and strip out there, but obviously that's not ideal and much more manual than I wanted.

Comment: @Strawberry. I'm scratching my head as well but it's my best guess given the question and the sample query. I'd be curious to see what you might have...